# How to Merge records in Hive table in Databricks using Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

```
%sql
MERGE INTO Employee as t
USING updates as s
ON s.Position = t.Position
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET 
  name=s.name,
  age=s.age,
  salary=s.salary,
  IsDelta=s.IsDelta,
  Modified=s.Modified,
  Created=s.Created
  address = updates.address
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT (Position, name, age, salary, IsDelta, Modified, Created) VALUES (s.Position,s.name,s.age,s.salary,s.IsDelta,s.Modified,s.Created)
```

for the above code i got the error:
**Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: MERGE destination only supports Delta sources.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Databricks only supports updates for delta (delta lake) tables.

The error message `Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: MERGE destination only supports Delta sources` indicates that you try the update on a non-delta-table.

Comment: Yes, the issue is due to delta table.Thanks

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.